# At which point is a condition # considered ill-conditioned?

Tags: condition-number

At which point is a condition # considered ill-conditioned? 
In my opinion, a condition # of $10^{10}$ corresponds to ill-conditioning obviously.

But what about a condition # of say, $2000$? $200$? $20$?

Comment: How high is up?

Comment: I saw a rule of thumb on wikipedia, but it required you to decide how many significant digits is acceptable.